# Why is PHP printing my function as a string?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following method:

```
function display_first_headline_background_color_option_field() {
    $selectedOption = get_option('first_header_headline_background_color');
    echo '<select name="first_header_headline_background_color" id="first_header_headline_background_color">
         <option value="0">Select A Color</option>
         <option value="blue" '.selected( $selectedOption, "blue" ).'>Blue</option>
         <option value="gray" '.selected( $selectedOption, "gray" ).'>Gray</option>
         <option value="orange" '.selected( $selectedOption, "orange" ).'>Orange</option>
         <option value="orange" '.selected( $selectedOption, "white" ).'>White</option>
         <option value="orange" '.selected( $selectedOption, "yellow" ).'>Yellow</option>
         </select>';
    }
```

That is printing the literal string `selected='selected'` before the `select` option shows on the page:

[image]

How can I edit my function to stop this from happening?

The `get_option` method is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) and the `selected` method is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/).

Comment: check the selected function, it may be printing instead of returning the value.

Comment: can you add the selected function to the question ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? You could share that `get_option` method to provide more insights

Comment: Question updated with the two functions referenced in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your **selected** function call to include **false** to not echo and instead return its value.

From the provided link:

```
selected( mixed $selected, mixed $current = true, bool $echo = true )
```

```
function display_first_headline_background_color_option_field() {
    $selectedOption = get_option('first_header_headline_background_color');
    echo '<select name="first_header_headline_background_color" id="first_header_headline_background_color">
         <option value="0">Select A Color</option>
         <option value="blue" '.selected( $selectedOption, "blue",false ).'>Blue</option>
         <option value="gray" '.selected( $selectedOption, "gray",false ).'>Gray</option>
         <option value="orange" '.selected( $selectedOption, "orange",false ).'>Orange</option>
         <option value="orange" '.selected( $selectedOption, "white" ,false).'>White</option>
         <option value="orange" '.selected( $selectedOption, "yellow",false ).'>Yellow</option>
         </select>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`selected` calls `echo` itself. You either need to tell it not use use echo by passing `false` as a third parameter:

```
echo '<select name="first_header_headline_background_color" 
     id="first_header_headline_background_color">
     <option value="0">Select A Color</option>
     <option value="blue" '.selected( $selectedOption, "blue", false ).'>Blue</option></select>';
```

or not include its result in your own `echo`:

```
echo '<select name="first_header_headline_background_color" 
     id="first_header_headline_background_color">
     <option value="0">Select A Color</option>
     <option value="blue" ';
selected( $selectedOption, "blue" );
echo '>Blue</option></select>';
```